# can anyone help me what does ...current State spread do in this code and generally what is its definition

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rxjs

```
const userReducer = (currentState, action)=>{
  switch (action.type){
   case 'SET_CURRENT_USER':
    return{
     ...currentState (???)
     currentUser: action.payload
    };
   default: 
    return currentState;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to update the state.

But for that to work so that react does not skip the rerender, you need to return a new object. If you would return the same object, react would compare the new and old object, notice that they are the same shallow object and will skip the render.

So to create a new object, you can do several things but the fatest is the spread operator: `...`.
It deconstructs an object and returns all values within. This work for arrays, strings and objects.

So by returning all entries into a new object, you make a shallow copy: same contents, but new object reference.

So what happens here is:

1. You create a new object `return {}`
2. You fill it with the current object by adding all entries from the currentState to the new state object `{...currentState}`. This gives a new object, but all entries are copied into the new object.
3. And finally you override the entry you want to override. The last instance will be selected. It would look like this:

   ```
   return{
      otherEntries,
      currentUser: currentState.currentUser, 
      currentUser: action.payload
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). You can use it to create a copy (a new place in the memory) of complex data structures such as arrays and objects.

Here's an example:

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const object1 = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
};

console.log('array1');
console.log(array1);
console.log('object1');
console.log(object1);

// An exact copy of array1
const array2 = [...array1];

// Here we take the data from array1 and add more data to it.
const array3 = [...array1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

console.log('array2');
console.log(array2);
console.log('array3');
console.log(array3);

// An exact copy of object1
const object2 = {...object1};

// Here we take the data from object1 and add more data to it.
const object3 = {...object1, c: 'c', d: 'd'};

console.log('object2');
console.log(object2);
console.log('object3');
console.log(object3);
```

In the specific case of a reducer, when you change a specific property of the state, you want to do so while not changing the previous properties. The spread operator lets you spread every property that the state already has, and then change just the property you want.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Im glad! If you liked the answer please consider marking it as the answer for your question @vaskaskhirtladze